# How do if I want to make a randomize colors but with a couple set I've made with onload methode while randomizing of an occcur?

Tags: css, google-apps-script, random, styles, stylesheet

Hy, I want to make different colors every single time the page has called or opened and with the couple set I've made at the table with the different personalisation of rows color. How do I make it true ???  This line of the **CSS** code I've try to achieves to make some goals :

I do try with the **Math** methode to get random some colors but I'd stuck with it. because it won't personalisation of couple set of colors. See the code I've made with javascript at the below this :

**---------------------------------------------------------- GS -----------------------------------------------------------------**

```
function randomColor(customColorsArray, takenColorsArray) {
 var text = "",
     colors = ["orange", "yellow", "red", "maroon"];

   if (customColorsArray && takenColorsArray) {
      var text = "["+colors+"]";
   }
     else if (!customColorsArray && !takenColorsArray) {
      text += colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
   }
     else {
      text += customColorsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * customColorsArray.length)];
  };

   return text;
}


function personalRandomColor(e, customColor1, customColor2, customColor3, customColor4) {
 var text = "";

   if (!customColor1) {
      if (e == "orange") {text += "white";}
      else if (e == "red") {text += "blue";}
      else if (e == "yellow") {text += "magenta";}
      else if (e == "maroon") {text += "almond";};

   } else {
       if (e == "orange") {text += customColor1;}
       else if (e == "yellow") {text += customColor2;}
       else if (e == "red") {text += customColor3;}
       else if (e == "maroon") {text += customColor4;};
   };

  return text;
}


function showTable() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp,
      ss = s.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sss = ss.getSheets(),
      Html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(result)
            .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
            .setWidth(545)
            .setHeight(500),
      customColorsArrays = randomColor('passingClass', 'takenColor'),
      randomFirstColor = 'yellow',
      skipFirstColor = customColorsArrays.replace('yellow,', ''),
      randomSecondColor = randomColor(toString(skipFirstColors)),
      result = "<head>
                   <style type='text/css'>
                      .gridview {
                        display: inline-block;
                        border-collapse: collapse;
                        margin: 0px 4px 4px 0;
                        box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #bbb;
                      }

                      .gridview, .gridview td {
                        margin: 0;
                        border:  1px solid #cccccc;
                      }

                      .gridview tr:nth-child(even) {
                        background-color: "+randomFirstColor+";
                      }

                      .gridview tr:nth-child(odd) {
                        background-color: "+randomSecondColor+";
                      }

                      .gridview td {
                        font-weight: normal;
                        text-align: left;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                      }

                      .gridview td {
                        padding: 4px 10px 5px 9px;
                      }
                   </style>
               </head>
            <table border=1 class='gridview'>";

                for (var i = 0; i < sss.length; i++) {
                   result += "<tr>";
                    result += "<td>" + sss[i].getName() + "</td>";
                   result += "</tr>";
                }
                result += "</table>";

        ss.toast(customColorsArrays+" & "+skipFirstColors+" & "+randomSecondColor, "Output Test", 50);
        ss.show(Html.setTitle("Show the Table at PopUp"));}
}
```

What I want is if the table have reloaded always shows the different colors of rows everytime the page has opened and it must be set with my personalisation I've set. Please, have a look to **personalRandomColor()** function In this case I would like such as **Orange just for nth-child(odd)** and **White for nth-child(even)** at the ***First Random Open*** and **Red for nth-child(odd)** and **Blue for nth-child(even)** at the ***Second Random Open*** and that's so on ... and on ... and on again and again and always again but with the condition of skipping the first colors !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var colors = ["#ccff99", "#e6ffb3", "#dfff80", "#ffffcc", "#ffff99", "#ffe6ff", "#ffcccc", "#ffcc99", "#ffe6b3", "#fff0b3"];
$(document).ready({
    var randomFirstColor = rando(colors);//grab a random color
    colors.splice(randomFirstColor.index, 1);//remove color from array so we don't risk picking it again. you can remove this line if you don't care whether the second color is the same as the first
    $(".gridview tr:nth-child(odd)").css({backgroundColor: randomFirstColor.value});//style odd rows
    $(".gridview tr:nth-child(even)").css({backgroundColor: rando(colors).value});//style even rows
});
```

You just have to import [Randojs](https://randojs.com) and [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) by pasting the following in the head tag of your html document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

OR, to exclude jQuery, try:

```
var colors = ["#ccff99", "#e6ffb3", "#dfff80", "#ffffcc", "#ffff99", "#ffe6ff", "#ffcccc", "#ffcc99", "#ffe6b3", "#fff0b3"];
$(window).on("load", function(){
    var randomFirstColor = rando(colors);//grab a random color
    colors.splice(randomFirstColor.index, 1);//remove color from array so we don't risk picking it again. you can remove this line if you don't care whether the second color is the same as the first
    var randomSecondColor = rando(colors);//grab another random color

    var gridviews = document.getElementsByClassName("gridview");
    for(var i = 0; i < gridviews.length; i++){//for each gridview...
        var rows = gridviews[i].getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for(var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++){//for each row in the gridview...
            if(j % 2 == 0){
                //style even
                rows[j].style.backgroundColor = randomFirstColor.value;
            }
            else{
                //style odd
                rows[j].style.backgroundColor = randomSecondColor.value;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You just have to import [Randojs](https://randojs.com) by pasting the following in the head tag of your html document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

---

Now that you've updated your post, I can see a problem with your code. You are assigning a string to the "result" variable, but you are breaking that string across multiple lines, like this:

```
var result = "example
of
bad
formatting";
```

You should be beginning and ending the quote on each line and adding a plus sign between them to join them together, like so:

```
var result = "example" + 
"of" + 
"good" + 
"formatting";
```

Once you get that fixed, make sure you put the html-string you've made into an element on the page and THEN call the random row color code I've given you.

Comment: Oh hy, @Aaron ...  it nice it's so pleasure to see this answer finally. I believe yes that was must be works greate. But I don't know why the GAS (google apps script) doesn't support with the jQuery script except the standard javascript. Chould we transform this to just standard javascript only Aaron ???    Excuseme to make you be work hard to this ...

Comment: I've updated my answer to offer a solution without jQuery.

Comment: Hy, @Aaron ...  It' stall won't work for GAS (google apps script). I'm getting frustate with it. How chould this achieves are getting nothing at my workaround ? What's worng else happen I need to know but I don't know where is the wrong came up come from ???   I try to update my description of my question above to describing more be detailed. Chould be hope this atemp will make be specificly more and be clearly to peaple to read my thread. Thanks one more time ...

Comment: I've updated my answer to point out what's wrong with your code.